# Javascript very simple: 'Read more'...' Show Less' Functionality to be applied to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I come here as a last resort for what I hope will be a quick and simply fix.

I have been playing around with some Javascript to create a 'Read more...' & '... Read Less' function on 6 different sections of the same page.

I have a body of text, I only want the first line to show of. The rest will be displayed upon clicking 'Read More...'

The below snippet shows that the code itself is working, however I am having a lot of trouble trying to actually apply this to my site / theme. Any attempts to apply this to the functions.php file.

```js
$(".more").toggle(function () {
    $(this).text("less..").siblings(".complete").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).text("more..").siblings(".complete").hide();
});
```

```css
.complete {
    display:none;
}
.more {
    color:navy;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="teaser">text goes here</span>

<span class="complete"> this is the 
complete text being shown</span>

<span class="more">more...</span>
```

The problem I am getting is, everytime I try to apply this to my functions.php, it creates an error that brings down my whole site.

Does anyone have any ideas what it is I'm doing wrong? Or how the best way to apply this to a wordpress theme would be?

The theme I'm using is Modernize.

Any help with this at all, will be great.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the above snippet to a js located in your assets folder, then in your functions.php file add a reference to this file using the `wp_register_script()`, `wp_enqueue_script()` and `add_action()` functions

```
function my_enqueued_scripts()
{

global $post;
// Register file that contains your js 
wp_register_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets /js/myscript.js');

if (isset($post)) {
    //load it when needed depending on the page -template-home.php
    if (is_page_template('template-home.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
    }
}
}
```

then call your function

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_scripts', 10);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. However, this is merely using Google to find a template answer to a standard problem of applying the JavaScript to a wordpress site. 

I have spent a significant amount of time, trying such sites and their suggestions with no luck. I am unsure if this is due to my applying the correct variable names or not. But using enqueue is something very hard to miss when researching this topic, so if could please make this more specific to my code and my issue. 

That would be great, otherwise simply telling me to 'Google it' would have sufficed.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood your question, I assumed you were asking how to enqueue JS files into a theme...could you elaborate more on the error you are getting ? Would you mind posting the functions.php code snippet ? I am not an wordpress expert but it might help others answer your question.